# Using Quotes with Commands in Scala Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, scala, shell, command-line

Trying to utilize the following command in scala bash file (sys.process._ has been imported):

```
val writeToLine5 = "sed -i '5a some text' to.file".!
```

the following error emerges:

```
> "sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `'';
```

The command itself works perfect in command line.

Have tried also:

```
"""sed -i "5a adding some text to" file.text""".!;
"sed -i \'5a adding some text to\' file.text".!;
```

Is there any scala shell scripting specialist here? Thank you!

PS: have asked on askubuntu.com. They have suggested to ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interpretation of the `'` character is done by the shell, not by `sed` itself, so it's usually easiest to ask the shell to do it for you.

```
import sys.process._

val writeToLine5 = Seq("sh", "-c", "sed -i '5a some text' to.file").!
```

But you *can* do the interpretation yourself.

```
val writeToLine5 = Seq("sed", "-i", "5a some text", "to.file").!
```

You could also use a Regex pattern to interpret the internal quotations, but it's error prone and I really don't recommend it.

```
val cmd = "sed -i '5a some text' to.file"
val res = cmd.split(""" +(?=([^'"]*['"][^'"]*['"])*[^'"]*$)""") //split on non-quoted spaces
             .map(_.replaceAll("['\"]",""))  //remove all the internal quote marks
             .toSeq.!
```